# Remove noise from image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm looking for a function/filter/algorithm to remove noise inside an object contour.

For example:

input image:

[image]

I want to get:

[image]

P.S. The object may have another form.

The idea was:

```
img_file = 'third.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
thresh0 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(s, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

img_2d = color.rgb2gray(img)
print(img_2d.shape)
print(thresh0.shape)
diff = cv2.absdiff(img_2d, thresh0)
mask = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
i_mask = mask > 10
canvas = np.zeros_like(thresh0, np.uint8)
canvas[i_mask] = thresh0[i_mask]

cv2.imshow('Result', canvas)
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", canvas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:683: 
    error: (-5:Bad argument) When the input arrays in 
    add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the 
    output array type must be explicitly specified in function 
    'cv::arithm_op'
```

thresh0 have the following view:

[image]

Maybe if I diff the original image and thresh0 I will get a clean image. By the way, it also corrupts the bottom. And doesn't clean up all the noise.

Comment: This is a very broad question. What have you tried so far based on your research, and what was the result?

Comment: I've tried some filters, for example GaussianBlur, Median. But they don't remove such type of noise.

Comment: That's all good detail to edit into your initial question to show a [mcve]

Comment: What makes the barcode noise, but not the circle in the tab of the can?

Comment: what are you trying to do with this `img_2d = color.rgb2gray(img)`? what's `color`?

Comment: Use connected components processing to remove all small regions from the binary image or get the largest black region, i.e, with the largest bounding box. I think you can do that after getting contours or from blobs in OpenCV